# some questions about insert() in python

Tags: python

```py
demo = []
for i in range(1,11):
    demo.insert(-1,i)
print(demo)
```

the result is [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]

```py
demo = []
for i in range(1,11):
    demo.insert(0,i)
print(demo)
```

the result is [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

**The former code block is used to realize something like append(). Obviously, something went wrong. However, when I changed the index from -1 to 0, just as the latter code block, it seems all right. I'm confused about that.**

Comment: side note: `L = []` followed by `L.insert(700, 6)` weirdly doesn't throw an `IndexError`

Comment: I know that, and it's recommanded by Python Official. I did that just making an attempt, then I find something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`-1` refers to the position of the last element, but you don't actually want to insert your elements there. You want to insert at the position *after* the last element, not the position *of* the last element.

If you want to do that with `insert`, you need to insert at index `len(demo)`. You cannot use a negative index to accomplish this.

Comment: 0 refers to the position of the first element, when i tried to insert something before that, I use demo.insert(0,i), it worked. Actually, I tried demo.insert(len(demo),i), it does produce the same effect as append().

Answer (score 0):

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x)

side note: a more pythonic approach might use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), so if you're not familiar with the concept, take a look.